# Subsetting OpenType Collection font in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox, opentype

I'm trying to embed a subset of noto-regular in my code. but I keeping on getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: OTF fonts do not have a glyf table

    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.OpenTypeFont.getGlyph(OpenTypeFont.java:66)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFSubsetter.addCompoundReferences(TTFSubsetter.java:481)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFSubsetter.getGIDMap(TTFSubsetter.java:136)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.TrueTypeEmbedder.subset(TrueTypeEmbedder.java:306)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.subset(PDType0Font.java:162)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1138)
```

I downloaded the font file `NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc` from https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/

Font subsetting works for `.ttf` fonts, as I haven't had any issues if the document I saved contains no special characters.

**EDIT**

It appears that true type collection fonts can have [shared glyf table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#collections) (makes sense since the font collection contains Japanese glyphs). So the individual PDType0Font parsed from `.ttc` can't be treated as an individual font.

I loaded the font using:

```
            ttc.processAllFonts((TrueTypeFont ttf) -> {
                PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttf, true);
                fontList.add(font);
            });
```

I'm guessing that there are extra work I needed to do to make this work, but I can't find any code samples anywhere.

**EDIT2**

Seems like the problem is that when subsetting specific OpenType font files, (which font collection contains) turns on an internal flag `isPostScript`. The flag is then checked and process is aborted when `getGlyph()` is called.

The following code generates the `glyf` table error when creating the pdf documents

```
        // downloaded from Noto project site
        String OTF_FILE = "./src/test/resources/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf";
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDFont otf = null;
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(OTF_FILE))) {
            otf = PDType0Font.load(doc, new OTFParser().parse(inputStream), true);
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            stream.setFont(otf, 10f);
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(100f, 600f);
            stream.showText("二ろほス反2化みた大第リきやね景手ハニエ者性ルヤリウ円脱");
            stream.endText();
            stream.close();
            doc.addPage(page);
            doc.save("test.pdf");
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            // failed
        }
```

but it will generate the pdf fine as soon as I set the subsetting parameter to true in the `PDType0Font.load` call

Similarily if I load the otf font through the collection:

```
        String OTF_FILE = "./src/test/resources/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc";
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDFont otf = null;
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(OTF_FILE))) {
            TrueTypeCollection ttc = new TrueTypeCollection(inputStream);
            otf = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttc.getFontByName("NotoSansCJKjp-Regular"), true);
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            stream.setFont(otf, 10f);
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(100f, 600f);
            stream.showText("二ろほス反2化みた大第リきやね景手ハニエ者性ルヤリウ円脱");
            stream.endText();
            stream.close();
            doc.addPage(page);
            doc.save("test.pdf");
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            // failed
        }
```

I either need to embed the whole font or subsetting will throw the error

**EDIT 3**
I ended up circumvent this by downloading the OTF font from "Language-specific OpenType/CFF (OTF)", which contains characters from all 4 regions and converted it using otf2ttf from [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools)

Comment: Instead of using the .ttc, just extract the individual fonts first, and use those directly. [Fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io) will let you do this quite easily. Alternatively, download the individual fonts instead of the font collection - you might have to grab Adobe's Source Sans CJK, though, which is _the same font_, just rebranded by Google to cover the CJK parts of their NOTO family, in collaboration with Adobe.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I tried converting / merging the font using FontForge but my ttf export is missing glyphs always. (I'm not sure if I missed a step but I just opened the ttc and try saving it to TrueType from the menu). I've also looked at Adobe Source Sans CJK which also doesn't have an official export of TTF.

Comment: there's a misnomer in the java API: wherever it says `ttf`, that's a legacy holdover from a different time, it uses the `ttf` namespace for OpenType fonts now, whether they use the ttf glyph tables (for historical reasons, files with `.ttf` extension), or whether they use cff glyph tables (for historical reasons, files with `.otf` extension). Both are OpenType fonts (in fact, there are even more glyph table types than just ttf/cff) so you should be able to download the official .otf files, and load them just fine.

Comment: Did you try `TrueTypeFont ttf = new TrueTypeCollection(…)` and then use that ttf font as parameter for `PDType0Font.open()`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

So I re-org my code and have attempted to load the font using:
`PDType0Font.load(doc, newOTFParser().parse(inputStream), SUBSET_FONT)`
it has gotten the same error when I'm trying to save to the pdf `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: OTF fonts do not have a glyf table`. ... Looks like this problem is actually strictly limited to otf fonts


@TilmanHausherr sorry I don't quite understand the error. `TrueTypeCollection` is not a subtype of `TrueTypeFont`

Comment: Sorry this was cut off. I meant `TrueTypeFont ttf = new TrueTypeCollection(new File("C:/windows/fonts/mingliu.ttc")).getFontByName("MingLiU")`

Comment: It sounds like it's time to show a [mcve] so people can see if they can replicate the problem.

Comment: I tried the last code and now it's indeed a MCVE. I opened the ttc file with DTL OTmaster and glyf is indeed missing, instead there is CFF which PDFBox doesn't support for file creation. I think the extension is incorrect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff "Collection files containing TrueType glyph outlnes should use the filename suffix .TTC. Collection files containing CFF or CFF2 outlines should use the file extension .OTC." See also https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/249

Comment: For those who want to use the otf2ttf tool, you can install it using pipe as it is described here: https://pypi.org/project/otf2ttf/